# javascript hta application as GUI for command prompt

Tags: javascript, html, shell, command-prompt

I need to create a simple HTA application that will ask for a command, then when I press a button that command should be executed in command prompt.

I have the following script so far which will only open a command prompt window but not read and run the script entered into the text box.

```
<html>
<head>

<HTA:APPLICATION>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function Run() {

x = document.getElementById("command").value;
shell = new ActiveXObject ("Shell.Application");
shell.ShellExecute("cmd.exe", "/k ", "", "open", 1);
}

</script>
</head>

<body bgcolor="grey">
<form>
<h1> Enter MS-DOS Command </h1>
<p> eg: ipconfig </p>

<textarea cols="20" rows="1" id="command"> </textarea> <br> <br>

<input type="button" value="Run" onclick="Run();">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
shell.ShellExecute("cmd.exe", "/k " + x, "", "open", 1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Thank you, thank you. I am just learning the basics, you have helped a lot !

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you are trying to do, but I can tell that you never do anything with your variable x. It appears that retrieve your text area value correctly but you never do anything with it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment, I will update you if it works :)

Comment: Thank you for your input, the above comment has answered my question :)